# React-pdf _ Convert into svg for preview

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, jspdf, pdf-viewer, react-pdf

React pdf PDFViewer generates iframe for the preview of the doc. However, on the original site of react-pdf.org, they display it in svg which is quite nice. Any idea, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think they used another library to display their output. I found another library named react-pdf https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf. I compared these examples:

[@react-pdf/renderer](https://react-pdf.org/repl)
[react-pdf](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-pdf/)

In the HTML section for displaying pdf, both use the same class names. Moreover, regarding the documentation of @react-pdf/renderer example only shows way to generate a file using ReactPDF.render. [react-pdf](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-pdf/) allows to render document as SVG.